# Generate Entities from an Existing Database with Point type attributes

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

This is my first post on StackOverflow and i'm very happy to join the community. I'm hoping that i'll contribute and help when i'll feel a bit more confident in my coding.

So, I'm new with all this Symfony and Doctrine/ORM thing, and I'm trying to generate my entities from my MySQL database. I've tables with some MySQL Point-type attributes and when i launch this command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml
```

I've this error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
Unknown database type point requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.
```

I tried installing [jhartikainen's doctrine2-spatial](https://github.com/jhartikainen/doctrine2-spatial) (and applied the changes to /app/config/config.yml as requested) and nothing changed.

I hope that someone could help. Thanks !

Ps - I could change the database and stop using the Point type for additional attributes (like x and y) but meh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the schema tool what doctrine type to map the `point` SQL type to:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        mapping_types:
            point: point
```